# how to reverse sort mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

An odd title I know, but I'm stumped. Say if I grab 20 rows like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 20
```

I then want to show them in reverse, from lowest to highest "views", how can I do this? I cannot simply order by "ASC" as that gives me the wrong result set. I want the highest views and to then order those from lowest to highest.

Comment: A nested query with reversed sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking Zerkms's idea:

```
Select * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `articles` 
    WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
    ORDER BY `views` DESC 
    LIMIT 20 
) as reverse_article 
ORDER BY views ASC
```

will let you double sort

1. The highest will get picked (inner select)
2. The lowest will get picked off first.

HOWEVER

you can also reverse sort via PHP by first getting your fetchALL and running the count backward from count() (which is your max size array) down to 0 (which is your highest array view)

take your pick

Answer (score 0):

You use a subquery for this.  The subquery chooses the right 20 rows, the outer query then sorts them according to your final criteria:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*
      FROM articles a
      WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
      ORDER BY views DESC
      LIMIT 20
     ) a
ORDER BY views ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 20) t ORDER BY `views` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Query:

```
(SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 20) ORDER by `views` ASC;
```

Comment: it wasn't me, but there is a simple reason: your answer is *too far* from being a valid mysql query.

Comment: I tested on MySQL Workbench and on my PHP sandbox and it works correctly. =(

Comment: Dont know "how" because I never thought it was wrong ... EDIT: `(<query>+<filters>) <more-filters>`

Comment: `(<query>+<filters>) <more-filters>` doesn't explain anything actually. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html - it should be invalid. I'm curious if it's an expected behaviour or just unintentionally supported syntax

Comment: I don´t think it is invalid, because the brackets say execute what is inside first. You cant add a filter after a `LIMIT`. So based on the question I get the **limited** response unsorted, and then sorted it.

Comment: the query **MUST** start with `SELECT`. That's how SQL queries are defined in mysql. Your query **DOES NOT** fit the grammar defined on the page I provided. So I don't have a good explanation why it works. Do you have an explanation from grammar perspective?