# Why the given syntax is valid in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22750898/251311) I've spotted a weird syntax:

```
(SELECT * FROM `articles` 
 WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
 ORDER BY `views` DESC 
 LIMIT 20
) ORDER by `views` ASC
```

which was executed by mysql well though.

Why I think it should fail:

1. The subquery doesn't have alias
2. The whole query lacks `SELECT` clause

I find it unexpected to run and don't have an explanation why it works.

It does not fit the grammar defined on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

So, why is it valid? Any references?

Comment: It's the same in SQL Server. Actually, you can add any number of pairs of brackets and they are just ignored.

Comment: @Szymon: if they were "just ignored" then you would get a syntax error about `ORDER BY` after `LIMIT`. Not to mention there would be 2 `ORDER BY`s

Comment: I'm not that sure about MySQL. I just found it interesing that in SQL Server something I wouldn't thing was correct still worked: `(((((select * from mytable))))) order by 1`

Comment: I associate parenthesized subqueries with `union all` and related operations.  This is very interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the alternative `UNION` syntax with a final `ORDER BY`.

This is what such a union between two selects looks like:

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION
(SELECT ...) ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...
```

And this is what such a union between *one* select looks like:

```
(SELECT ...) ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...
```

Not related to subqueries at all.

This isn't documented in MySQL, but is obvious from [the grammar](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7322):

```
top_level_select_init:
        SELECT_SYM
        {
            Lex->sql_command= SQLCOM_SELECT;
        }
        select_init2
        | '(' select_paren ')' union_opt
        ;


/* Need select_init2 for subselects. */
union_select_init:
        SELECT_SYM select_init2
        | '(' select_paren ')' union_opt
        ;

...

union_opt:
        /* Empty */ { $$= 0; }
        | union_list { $$= 1; }
        | union_order_or_limit { $$= 1; }
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is useful when you want to sort the end result of the UNION.

The following would sort only the last SELECT:

```
SELECT …
UNION
SELECT …
UNION
SELECT … ORDER BY views
```

But this would sort the whole result:

```
(SELECT …)
UNION
(SELECT …)
UNION
(SELECT …) ORDER BY views
```

You're doing something like this query, but you've got just one SELECT.

Comment: I agree `UNION` is useful and it's explained in the documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html `UNION`s work according to documentation. In the original query there are no `UNION`s though

Comment: it's still using the `UNION` syntax; there just happens to be only one `SELECT`, so the `UNION` keyword never appears.

Comment: @Eevee: `UNION` syntax grammar **REQUIRES** to have at least 2 `SELECT`s: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html So I don't see how it can be used with only one `SELECT`

Comment: @zerkms look at the very first comment on that page  :)  nothing there says the paren form requires 2 selects, either.

Comment: @Eevee: `SELECT ...
UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...
[UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...]` --- do you know how to read this grammar?

Comment: @zerkms notice that parentheses and an outer `ORDER BY` do not appear anywhere in that example.  it's not the same syntax.  (of course you need two statements to make an unparenthesized `UNION`; with one statement, you just have that one statement.)

Comment: @Eevee: it's not. I see the grammar on the page that requires **2** `SELECT`s. Not sure **WHY** you think it is used in this case. What your assumption is based on?

Comment: @zerkms the parenthesized grammar is not defined on that page.  there are only examples.  the mysql docs are pretty shoddy about explicit grammar productions anyway.  here's the grammar, you can decide for yourself whether this is related to union syntax: https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7322

Comment: @Eevee: there is actually a `union_order_or_limit` token! That is used  as a `union_opt` in `'(' select_paren ')' union_opt`. So **this** is an answer. Could you please post one?